# JSON golang boolean omitempty

Tags: json, go

I'm having issues with writing a golang library for an api. The json aspect of booleans is causing issues.

Let's say the default value of a boolean is true for an api call.

If I do

```
SomeValue bool `json:some_value,omitempty`
```

and I don't set the value through the library, the value will be set to true. If I set the value to false in the library, omitempty says that a false value is an empty value so the value will stay true through the api call.

Let's take out the omitempty and have it look like this

```
SomeValue bool `json:some_value`
```

Now I have the opposite issue, I can set the value to false but if I don't set the value then the value will be false even though I expect it to be true.

Edit: How do I maintain the behavior of not having to set the value to true while also being able to set the value to false?

Comment: when you need to differentiate between unset and zero values, use a pointer.

Comment: That did it. Thanks @JimB

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[**Use pointers**](https://play.golang.org/p/L5rUx1BHT5)

```go
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type SomeStruct struct {
    SomeValue *bool `json:"some_value,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    t := new(bool)
    f := new(bool)

    *t = true
    *f = false

    s1, _ := json.Marshal(SomeStruct{nil})
    s2, _ := json.Marshal(SomeStruct{t})
    s3, _ := json.Marshal(SomeStruct{f})

    fmt.Println(string(s1))
    fmt.Println(string(s2))
    fmt.Println(string(s3))
}
```

Output:

```
{}
{"some_value":true}
{"some_value":false}
```

Comment: If I don't want to use some_value. Instead of it if I use `json:"true,omitempty"`, will it work?

Comment: @IFTEKHARIASIF - the first item in the `json` tag for go is the name of the variable key in json that you are mapping the <-- field to.

Answer (score 1):

As a continuation to [gaav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3169754/gavv)'s answer. I had the same problem with unmarshalling instead. If you want to check that the value is provided or not, simply check if the pointer is nil or not

```
type SomeStruct struct {
    SomeValue *bool `json:"some_value,omitempty"`
}

func HandleApiRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  body := new(SomeStruct)

  reqBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
  if err != nil {
         panic(err)
  }

  err := json.Unmarshal(reqBody, body)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  if body.SomeValue != nil {
    // SomeValue is provided in the body and is a valid boolean
    // Do something with *body.SomeValue
    log.Println("Some Value is:", *body.SomeValue)
  } else {
    // SomeValue was NOT sent in json body
    // Will panic with a fault if you tried accessing *body.SomeValue
  }
}
```